# multiple formulas containing text in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I hope you can help me with this:

I have a report showing all information in cell *A1* as:

```
LAST NAME First Name (email adress).
```

By googling I came this far:

1. Make LAST NAME normal using `=PROPER(A1)`
2. Get rid of the email adress `=TRIM(LEFT(A1;FIND("(";A1)-1))`
3. Switch last name with first name `=MID(A1&" "&A1;FIND(" ";A1)+1;LEN(A1))`

Is it possible to do all three in ONE cell?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please add some sample data with desired results to help us understanding your issue. (take a screenshot, upload it to e.g. [imgur](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), then post the link in your question; or you can format your data as a table [here](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)).

Comment: Why is this in 1 cell? Are you simply trying to achieve `First Name Last Name` in the cell? Is there a guarantee there is never a middle name?

Comment: Actually, sometimes there is a two worded last name. It's a big report and I need the formatting to be First Name Last Name indeed. But I figured I could live with a little mess up if the double worded last name like 'De Vries' or even triple 'Van den Veen' is not all correct. I couldn't find a solution to this issue, so this is the closest I could get to achieving an ok result.
I would like it to be in one cell preferably so it's bulletproof for me- I am not the only person working in the sheet and this way I can easily see if there is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

With this in cell **A1**:

```
CABAL John (john.cabal@gmail.com)
```

In **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),2*999-998,999))&" "&PROPER(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))
```

[image]

This assumes a space before the email.